# Automatic order entry help request in VA01 in your sap logo with Excel vba?

Tags: vba

I want to enter an automatic order to sap (va01) using the data in Excel cells.
From column A to column E in Excel;
A2 cell ordering A1 cell "x"
B1 cell receives goods B2 cell "y"
C1 cell customer reference C2 cell "z"
D1 cell product code D2 cell "w"
E1 cell product amount E2 cell "1"
If my macro was only one item for the customer's order, I would not have a problem, but since there were more than one product, the problem became unsolvable for me.

The script is as follows, starting from the macro cell A2, it brings the values ​​to the orderer ( x ), the financial recipient ( y ), the customer reference ( z ) in sap va01, but in my Trials, I have a problem and I could not find a solution, for example, the customer orders more than one product and my macro It just takes the product and quantity in cell D2 and E2 and saves it, but I want it to save all the products and quantities for x, y and z (for example, the customer has 3 items of product order D2 : D4 needs to receive up to and E2 : E4)
I hope I can explain the problem
I am waiting for your valuable support.

Comment: The codes I used are as above

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub HANA_VA01()

   

    Zaman = Timer

   

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 

10

On Error Resume Next

Set SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

Err.Clear

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set proc = WshShell.Exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe")

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")

GoTo 10:

End If

On Error GoTo 0

 

Set Appl = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine

Set Connection = Appl.OpenConnection("HANA")

Set session = Connection.Children(0)

'''''''''

session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = "x"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = "y"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").Text = "TR"

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

On Error Resume Next

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/radMULTI_LOGON_OPT2").Select

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/radMULTI_LOGON_OPT2").SetFocus

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

On Error GoTo 0

 

 

Dim objExcel

Dim objsheet, intRow, i

Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.application")

Set objsheet = objExcel.Workbooks("SİPARİŞ_GİRİŞİ").Sheets("oto")

 

 

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nva01"

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-AUART").Text = "zs01"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VKORG").Text = "0289"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VTWEG").Text = "10"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-SPART").Text = "00"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-SPART").SetFocus

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-SPART").caretPosition = 2

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

 

For i = 2 To objsheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

col1 = Trim(CStr(objsheet.Cells(i, 1).Value))

col2 = Trim(CStr(objsheet.Cells(i, 2).Value))

col3 = Trim(CStr(objsheet.Cells(i, 3).Value))

col4 = Trim(CStr(objsheet.Cells(i, 4).Value))

col5 = Trim(CStr(objsheet.Cells(i, 5).Value))

 

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/txtVBKD-BSTKD").Text = col3

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/subPART-SUB:SAPMV45A:4701/ctxtKUAGV-KUNNR").Text = col1

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/subPART-SUB:SAPMV45A:4701/ctxtKUWEV-KUNNR").Text = col2

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/ctxtRV45A-MABNR[1,0]").Text = col4

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/txtRV45A-KWMENG[3,0]").Text = col5

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/txtRV45A-KWMENG[3,0]").SetFocus

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG/txtRV45A-KWMENG[3,0]").caretPosition = 19

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

 

objExcel.Cells(i, 6).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text

 

 

aux = col1 & " " & col2 & " " & col3 & " " & col4 & " " & col5

 

Next

  

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 

 

MsgBox "veriler işlendi!!!" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _

           "İşlem süresi ; " & Format(Timer - Zaman, "0.00") & " Saniye", vbInformation

 

 

End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).